# Autocomplete-alt with angular not working for injected localdata

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt for my autocomplete
trying get autocomplete-alt to work by injecting data via a angular factory service does not seem to be working for me.

i have a remote service that feeds the data , but i want to expose it via factory so i can reuse it other places.

here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/2hUV0zZAXoUPNo4ff2Nl?p=preview

Below is the snippet from pluker where i bind vm.artistsData

```
app.factory('artistService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var artistsList = [];

  var factory = {
    getArtists: function() {
      $http.get('artists.json').success(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          artistsList.push(data[i]);
        }
      });
    },
    getArtistsData: function() {
      return artistsList;
    },
    clearArtistsData: function() {
      artistsList = [];
    }
  }
  return factory;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'artistService', function($scope, artistsService) {
  var vm = this;
  artistsService.getArtists();
  vm.artistsData = artistsService.getArtistsData();
  vm.itemsByPage = 4;
  vm.searchQuery = '';
  vm.name='';
  console.log(vm); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plunkr suffers from a few issues:

1. You need to specify `ng-app="plunker"` in your index.html
2. You need to specify a name for the controller, if you are using `this` instead of `$scope`. `ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm"` will do, but a more descriptive name is advisable.
3. The directive does not work on `<input>` elements, use a `div` instead or use the element notation for that directive.
4. The attribute `title-fields` does not exist, it is `title-field`.
5. In this case it is not `ng-model` but `selected-object`.
6. (Use a loadable module script for angucomplete-alt)

Have a look at the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/oWFIJh6Q7jtq0Efn6oQ2?p=preview